# How do I set up the Bash shell to automatically line change after entering a command?

Tags: bash

I could use that in zsh for automatically line change after entering a command, but I don't know how to do that in bash.

```
    build_prompt() {df
  enter code hereRETVAL=$?
  prompt_status
  prompt_virtualenv
  prompt_aws
  prompt_context
  prompt_dir
  prompt_git
  prompt_bzr
  prompt_hg
  **prompt_newline** # typed code
  prompt_end
}

# typed code
**prompt_newline() {
  if [[ -n $CURRENT_BG ]]; then
    echo -n "%{%k%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR
%{%k%F{blue}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR"
  else
    echo -n "%{%k%}"
  fi
  echo -n "%{%f%}"
  CURRENT_BG=''
}**
```

Answer (score 2):

By setting **PROMPT_COMMAND** to a function that echoes a newline character, you can achieve the desired effect.

Place this in your **.bashrc** or **.bash_profile** file to make it persistent across sessions:

```
add_newline() {
    echo -e "\n"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}add_newline"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want a newline to be printed after each command, simply prefix that newline to the `PS1` variable, which holds your prompt:

```
PS1="\n$PS1"
```